# Printing PDF pages onto network printer (IP address)

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I am trying to print PDF pages onto our network printers.

I have searched and found tons of similar queries but everybody suggested to add the network printer as local printer and it should be fine.

I did exactly the same and is able to print, but using the printer name (and not the IP.)

My question is, can we print it using the IP and not the name of the printer ??

And I need this because what if tomorrow we change the Printer then I have to change that in the code again.  I am currently using GhostScript for printing using following code.

```
 string PrinterIP = "10.0.6.251"; //OKI B430(PL) - When I specify the name it works fine. but it gives me error with IP
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.Arguments = @" -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=" + Convert.ToString(1) + @" -sDEVICE=ljet4 -sOutputFile=""\\spool\" + PrinterIP + @""" """ + PDFFilePath + @"""";
 startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.07\\bin\\gswin64c";//GhostScriptPath; 
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 system.Diagnostics.Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: hi, if you are worried about code getting changed with change in printer, why don't you put the PrinterIP in config file and read it from there. so that you can avoid any code changes

Comment: you need to give the printer name as `\\ipAddress\[name of printer]`

Comment: @CSharped Thanks, can do that.. But again I have to make changes in config file. Actually we have some information in the database (which I cannot modify), about the type of document to be printed on specific printer(IP). So all I have is IP address only. Though I can find out the name of the printers and put it in config file against the IP but I want to avoid that... I hope that make sense...

Comment: @Damith Thanks, but I am able to print it using the Printer name. I am having issues while printing using IP address of the printer.